# MERGE statement with "WITH FUNCTION" definition

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I am trying to use a function declared in WITH clause, into a MERGE statement.
Here is my code:

```
create table test
  (c1 varchar2(10),
   c2 varchar2(10),
   c3 varchar2(10));



insert into test(c1, c2) values ('a', 'A');
insert into test(c1, c2) values ('b', 'A');

select * from test;

begin
with function to_upper(val varchar2) return varchar is
begin
    return upper(val);
end;
merge into test a
    using (select * from test) b
on (upper(a.c1) = upper(b.c2))
when matched then 
    update set a.c3 = to_upper(a.c1);
end;
```

but I am getting this error:

> Error report - ORA-06550: line 2, column 15: PL/SQL: ORA-00905:
> missing keyword ORA-06550: line 2, column 1: PL/SQL: SQL Statement
> ignored ORA-06550: line 6, column 1: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol
> "MERGE"
> 06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
> *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
> *Action:

Can someone explain why it is not working, please?

Thank you,

Comment: @AlexPoole: I edit the code by adding the usage of the function.

Answer (score 5):

The `with` clause is part of the `select` syntax. As the [railroad diagram](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__CHDDCHGF) for that shows, the only thing that's valid after the `with` clause is the `select` keyword - you don't have that, hence the error you are seeing.

As [the documentation also says](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__BABJCBCC) says:

> The *plsql_declarations* clause lets you declare and define PL/SQL functions and procedures. You can then reference the PL/SQL functions in the query in which you specify this clause, as well as its subqueries, if any.

and

> If the query in which you specify this clause is not a top-level SELECT statement, then the following rules apply to the top-level SQL statement that contains the query:
>
> - If the top-level statement is a SELECT statement, then it must have either a WITH *plsql_declarations* clause or the WITH_PLSQL hint.
> - If the top-level statement is a DELETE, MERGE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement, then it must have the WITH_PLSQL hint.

So, you can't apply the `with` clause to the whole `merge` statement, you can only use it as part of a query within that, i.e. in the `using` clause:

```
merge /*+ WITH_PLSQL */ into test a
    using (
        with function to_upper(val varchar2) return varchar is
        begin
            return upper(val);
        end;
        select to_upper(c2) as c2 from test
    ) b
on (upper(a.c1) = b.c2)
when matched then 
    update set a.c3 = upper(a.c1);
```

Without the `/*+ WITH_PLSQL */` hint this would error with "ORA-32034: unsupported use of WITH clause" (though only if you actually call the function, otherwise the complier seems to strip the unused function out and not complain about it).

But the function is still only in scope for the `using` clause; you can't refer to it in the `on` or `update` clauses. You would need to do any function calls within the `using` clause; and if you need the same function applied to anything from the target table, you would need to repeat the function and call that with the `into` clause, e.g.:

```
merge /*+ WITH_PLSQL */ into (
        with function to_upper(val varchar2) return varchar is
        begin
            return upper(val);
        end;
        select to_upper(c1) as c1, c3 from test
    ) a
    using (
        with function to_upper(val varchar2) return varchar is
        begin
            return upper(val);
        end;
        select to_upper(c2) as c2 from test
    ) b
on (a.c1 = b.c2)
when matched then 
    update set a.c3 = a.c1;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=78464f22c6c6326b6791f90b8d9bb290) showing things that do and don't work.

It's quite a contrived example so it would probably be clearer with a more real-world scenario.

Comment: Something is weir. The code you provided, In db<>fiddle it works exactly as you described.
In my 12c, it gives me the ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: @mikcutu -  hmm, interesting. Running in SQL Developer against a 12.1 database works - but only if each merge statement is terminated with a `/` on a line on its own (like a PL/SQL block).

Comment: hmm, still interesting. I am using your suggestion, adding a "/" on the last line of the code, but got another error: ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables
I will test tomorrow with other client and/or make an update to my SQL Developer.

Comment: @mikcutu - to make it work I had to change one of the test c2 values; otherwise the `on` clause matched multiple rows, which gives that error - essentially because the same source row could be updated multiple times, which could cause unpredictable results. It's nothing to do with the function - [same thing happens without it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2f0c07919c4bd167782728e00ad162fa) with your original values. Changing client won't help. Again, it's difficult to advise from a contrived example, but maybe your real data has something else unique.

Comment: that's right. It was a silly mistake; but here is my sqllive: https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/f?p=590:1:5502920764807::NO:RP::

Comment: @mikcutu - I just see a blank worksheet if I follow that link. I haven't used Live SQL much but I think you might need to save your script and then make it public. Or recreate it as a db<>fiddle.

Comment: For unknown reason, today it worked fine in SQL Developer as well as in PLSQL Developer but only with "/" on last line. Now, the question is: since it does not allow ";", how can I put it into an anonymous block?

Comment: @mikcutu - huh, yes, interesting...if you really need to, the only way I can see to do it is with dynamic SQL, which is awkward. [Added to db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f93a4558766d8d03e9b34426208ebec6) and checked that works in 12.1 too.

Comment: I'm assuming you can't create a standalone function, or a package with the function? A local (to the anonymous block) function wouldn't be callable from SQL, sadly. It might be worth asking a new question specifically about doing this within a block. I realise that is what this question actually shows but as there was no other PL/SQL code I guess I assumed that was a mistake...

Comment: the initial question was about how to use WITH FUNCTION ... into a MERGE statement. I encapsulated the entire code in BEGIN ... END as I would like to use it in a store procedure. As it is not possible only with dynamic SQL, this is something else. 
I wanted to not store the function in DB to avoid context switch. 
Anyway, your details help me a lot.

Comment: I raised same topic on Ask Tom, and it seems it is a bug.